# How to stop running activeadmin on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I need to separate admin panel from the regular application, so I want to run two instances where A will be responsible for regular app and B will be responsible for admin panel.

Comment: open one tab for actual site and open the second tab for admin from a web browser

Comment: Asked about server project structure, not about browser

Answer (score 1):

Try adding conditional logic to your `routes.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self) if ENV['ADMIN_PANEL']
```